# Console application has different process results than as service

Tags: c#, service

I'm having trouble finding my mistake. The goal is a service that finds the correct chrome process and sets the window into the foreground. It's a quick and dirty solution to keep a website always on display. When ran as console application, one of the processes has a MainWindowHandle that's not 0 and that's how I target the process. But when ran as a service, all the MainWindowHandles are 0.

I tried changing the account which runs the service from local system to my user account, but the results were the same. For some reason the service doesn't recognize the chrome main window handle? Here's the code:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
foreach (var process in processes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("itemToInt32: " + process.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32());                  
    if (process.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32() != 0)
    {
        Process targetProcess = Process.GetProcessById(process.Id);
        IntPtr handler = targetProcess .MainWindowHandle;
        SetForegroundWindow(handler);
        Console.WriteLine("handler: " + handler + "Process ID: " + targetProcess.Id);                             
    }
}
```

This might not be the most elegant approach, but that's what I came up with. So here's the output when ran as console application:

```
itemToInt32: 0
itemToInt32: 0
itemToInt32: 0
itemToInt32: 0
itemToInt32: 328360
handler: 328360 Process ID: 25516
itemToInt32: 0
itemToInt32: 0
itemToInt32: 0
```

Compared to the output (to eventlog) when ran as a service, the reason why it doesn't work is clear, none of the process.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32() has another value than 0:

```
itemToInt32: 0
itemToInt32: 0
itemToInt32: 0
itemToInt32: 0
itemToInt32: 0
itemToInt32: 0
itemToInt32: 0
itemToInt32: 0
```

But why is the output for the service different, does anybody know what's happening?

Comment: Services cannot interact with *any* desktops (and the windows thereon). You've gone down the wrong path by assuming they can.

Comment: As noted, this is a doomed idea that can never work.  What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?  It sounds like you want some kind of kiosk operating mode?

Comment: Exactly. We have information shown per website but another application keeps jumping in front of chrome from time to time. It's an old system that can't be changed much.

Comment: Chrome can do this [out of the box](https://superuser.com/questions/716426/running-latest-chrome-for-windows-in-kiosk-mode).

Comment: We are running chrome in kiosk mode. But when the other application gets priority, the windows taskbar stays in front even tho it is set to auto hide. That's what I'm trying to change